# Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests on deploy to private network

Tags: contract-deployment, private-blockchain, truffle-migration, web3j

I know there are many similar questions, but I've been through all of them and haven't got the answer I'm looking for.

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract (that's already been compiled and deployed in Rinkeby) to a private network.

1_initial_migrations.js

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations, {from: "[address]"});
};
```

2_deploy.js

```
// migrations/2_deploy.js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
const compsc = artifacts.require("compsc");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(compsc);
};
```

truffle-config.js

```
const PrivateKeyProvider = require('truffle-privatekey-provider');
const { projectId, mnemonic } = require('./secrets.json');

const privateKey = "[PK]";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      provider: () => new PrivateKeyProvider(privateKey, `[PROVIDER_URL]`),
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 4612388,
      timeoutBlocks: 200
    },
    nodalblock: {
      provider: () => new PrivateKeyProvider(privateKey, `[IP:PORT]`),
      network_id: 4660
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.0",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    }
  },
  db: {
    enabled: false
  }
};
```

And I'm always getting:

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================
Current account balance 0

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests..

    at /node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
Truffle v5.2.6 (core: 5.2.6)
Node v10.16.0
```

I've read that there's a problem with some web3 functions being async but being called synchronous by Truffle (at least, I think I understood the problem that way) but I can't get what I need to change/do differently to make it work.

The versions I'm using are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "truffle": "^5.2.6",
    "truffle-privatekey-provider": "^1.5.0"
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Did you try using the official package @truffle/hdwallet-provider?

Comment: Hi Ismael, yes, I did try hdwallet as well, to no avail.
Apparently, something's wrong with the Parity installation on the private network and bigger smart contracts, I deployed it on another blockchain we have (Geth with Clique PoA) and it deployed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better for you to use the official `HDWalletProvider` instead of the `PrivateKeyProvider`.

For that, you need to include it:
`const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');`

And in the networks, configure it like this:

```
goerli: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider({
        privateKeys: [process.env.SECRET],
        providerOrUrl: process.env.INFURA_URL
      }),
      network_id: "5"
    },
```